# やっぱり <Noun> か - why is it ok to have both?

Tags: meaning, particle-か

Example:

やっぱり初心者か

I'm confused how a sentence can have both:

- やっぱり, which IIUC suggests that in the end, the speaker found that the things are just as expected
- か which indicates that the speaker isn't certain yet

The two words would seem to correspond to rather incompatible nuances:

- Ah so she really is a newbie, just like I thought!
- Ah I guess she must be a newbie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

か is not just a question marker but also is a sentence-end particle used to confirm something with a bit of exclamatory feeling. This type of か is pronounced without a rising intonation. If your example sentence was pronounced without a rising intonation, it means the speaker is now certain that she is a newbie.

Examples:

- そうか。
  I see. / Oh is that so. / Alright.
- そうか？⤴ (with rising intonation)
  Is that so? / Really?
- 君か!
  Oh it's you!
- 大きくなったじゃないか!
  You've grown up, haven't you!

Comment: Is it related to the role of かしら in a sentence "よかったら手伝ってくれるかしら" ? よかったら makes the sentence a request, so かしら seems out of place if it expresses doubt.